# Start Application within a DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

So I want to create a Dll that contains an application. My code:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch(ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            StartApp();
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

And the StartApp function:

```
void StartApp()
{   
    //some declartions
    iPtr->Start();
}
```

The thing is that the function Start() is running in a continuous loop (sth like while(true)) and I think that's the problem cause the dll never gets to break and return true. I tried to run it in a different thread but this isn't working.

So my question is what can I do to use the dll?

Is there a problem if DllMain doesnt finish and doesn't return TRUE?

Comment: >>  I want to create a Dll that contains an application
Normally an exe is needed to start an application. A DLL cannot do it alone. So, who is loading this DLL?

Comment: @Unni So I want to make a c++ app that will load the dll and the dll shall load another app

Comment: You mean your DLL will launch another .exe? Then where is the question of while(true) loop? After launching the exe, the StartApp() function exits, right?

Comment: @Unni So my main program starts this DLL(1). The DLL(1) should call a function situated in DLL(2). The function from DLL(2) has the while(true) loop. So my DLL(1) doesn't return anything since the DLL(2) function never finishes.

Comment: @Thanatos: Are you trying to make a virus? Why do u need such a weird functionality?

Comment: @nakiya I need to do it this way because I am writing in 2 different languages C++ and C# and I use some functions from C#, put them in a DLL and now I use them in c++ .

Comment: @UnniThe StartApp() never finishes because of the while(true) loop situated in iPtr->Start().

Comment: So, Start() calls some C# methods? That is something I have never done. I'm sorry that I can't help with that.

Comment: @Thanatos Based on your comments, I think two different applications, one in c++ and the other in c# with some inter-process communication is a more viable solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a problem is DllMain doesn't return, as the documentation states:

`When a DLL entry-point function is called because a process is loading, the function returns TRUE to indicate success. For processes using load-time linking, a return value of FALSE causes the process initialization to fail and the process terminates. For processes using run-time linking, a return value of FALSE causes the LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx function to return NULL, indicating failure. (The system immediately calls your entry-point function with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH and unloads the DLL.) The return value of the entry-point function is disregarded when the function is called for any other reason.`

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You may create a wrapper function for the StartApp function, and expose it via your dll. After that you can call the exported StartApp function from your executable (after you loaded the dll). Make sure you call it from a different thread as it will block.

Comment: Cum am zis mai sus nu pot sa creez un nou thread pentru ca aplicatia nu il baga in seama trece pur si simplu mai departe (am un singur procesor) si aplicatia nu functioneaza, am incercat sa il astept cu WaitForSingleObject dar degeaba

Comment: Let's keep it in English. Maybe some other people need this information. As Hans Passant says in his comment, if CreateThread does not return false, it should work. Can you post more information? Is the thread function even called (you can add some traces)? Can you add some code for the StartApp function? Are you calling CreateThread with the CREATE_SUSPENDED option? Use yout debugging skills.

Comment: I can't use "my debugging skills" since i use Interop. I have a C# dll that im calling from c++ and there is the problem. If I run the c++ dll from c# it works, but when I'm calling it from c++ it sometimes work/sometimes doesn't. If i run it by going manually to it, it doesnt work, but if I use the debugger it works

Comment: Non-deterministic behavior might be caused by a race condition. Please check your threads. Can post some code? Otherwise I'm just guessing here...

Comment: I've solve it: instead of loading the DLL in the switch block, I actually put the StartApp in an extern C block. All I have to do now is to load the dll and the use GetProcAddress to locate it and run it. Although when I said it comment nr. 3 it was because somehow VS 6.0 use the program and links it with the normal project. It wasn't working when I was going manually because of dependencies need.